# Publish (Deploying) my website

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web, publish

I am publish my website application . I am storing all my data in XML  files in App_Data folder and in some other folder too.
The steps i follow are
1) Publish using visual studio 2010 asp.net c#.
2) Then copy my all file from "\Debug\PackageTemp" and paste in "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" 
The files in wwwroot are being used my inetmgr and my system now acts as a server.

Am i doing it right ?


One More Question . 

If i publish and follow the steps as mentioned above ,then for second time all my data (in XML file)get reseted.
So i wrote a batch file which will keep all my data files  in backup and after deploy my website i vl  copy my backup files in respectively folder ..but i dont know when to call my batch file .Is there anyway to call these batch file while i am doing my deployment ..

OR 
there is any feature provided by microsoft visual studio to keep backup and automatically copy these files  or not to modify some files

Answer (score 0):

Once you Publish your solution, try selecting the Publish Method as "File System". Then point the target location to any folder on your system/network and click on the Publish button in the dialog.

Just copy all those files and directories that are created in that location, to either your FTP folder in case of a Web Deployment or to a local/network folder and configure a website from IIS.